# Joomla!3.6.x - BDD - ACL inconsistent

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, database, acl, category

I have got a too amazing feature regarding ACL : a category and a sub-category for which ACL of three user groups is inconsistent. One group's got herited right at sub-category however it hasn't right at the parent category...
These 2 pictures give all needed info to (non)understand (!)
[image: ACL screens]
[image: BDD relations]

Thanks a lot for advice

Comment: You've provided lots of information, but what's the question? Please be specific.

Comment: @000000 : Sorry by that. the fact is that the usergroup "fiche_pratique_DSI_agents" has no right at category "Mon service" but it has right (inherited-autorised) at category "informatique et sig" which is a subcategory of "Mon service". It should have "inherited-refused".

Answer (score 2):

The permissions to create and edit in category "Informatique et SIG" for user group "fiche_pratique_DSI_agents" are set to "inherit". They should inherit from the parent category "Mon service" and therefore should be "not allowed".

Maybe something with your #__assets table is wrong.

**Before you do anything else, make a backup of your database.**

Then I would try to change the value in column "rules" for category "Informatique et SIG" in table #_assets from {"core.create":{"9":1,"83":1} ... to {} (same value as for category "Mon service") and see if that works. If nothing happened or something went wrong --> revert to backup.

If it did not help you could install an extension, for example [ACL-Manager](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/acl-manager). It will show you if there are any problems with your ACL and fix them for you.